# How to convert HashMap value to Java Pojo?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am working on consuming external API in spring boot application. I have written my JSON response that is coming from external API using RestTemplate and exchange() method of HttpEntity.

Below is the response:

```java
String json = """
        {
            "links": {
                "RCDSO - Production Environment Cost": {
                    "href": "href 1"
                },
                "RCDSO - Development & UAT Environment Cost": {
                    "href": "href 2"
                },
                "RCDSO - Total Cost for Prod - Compugen Managed": {
                    "href": "href 3"
                },
                "RCDSO - Virtual Machine Cost": {
                    "href": "href 4"
                },
                "RCDSO - Azure File Storage Cost": {
                    "href": "href 5"
                },
                "RCDSO - Azure Backup and Site Recovery": {
                    "href": "href 6"
                },
                "RCDSO - Azure App Services Cost": {
                    "href": "href 7"
                }
            }
        }
        """;
Map<String, Map<String, String>> links = JsonPath.read(json, "$.links");
links.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("k = " + key);
    System.out.print("v = ");
    value.forEach((key2, value2) -> {
        System.out.println("key = " + key2 + " : value = " + value2);
    });
});
```

In above code, I tried to get values from Map. Now I want to convert into my POJO class.

Below is my Pojo named OlapCustomReportResponse.java:

```java
public class OlapCustomReportResponse {
    private String name;
    private String href;
}
```

I extracted key from outer loop and on the basis of key I extracted value from inner loop as below:

```
Key 1 = RCDSO - Production Environment Cost
Key 2 = href : Value 2 = some url related to key 1

Key 2 = RCDSO - Development & UAT Environment Cost
Key 2 = href : Value 2 = some url related to key 2 

Key 3 = RCDSO - Total Cost for Prod - Compugen Managed
Key 2 = href : Value 2 = some url related to key 3

Key 4 = RCDSO - Virtual Machine Cost
Key 2 = href : Value 2 = some url related to key 4 

.... and so on
```

I want my OlapCustomReportResponse.java should look something like below:

```json
[
  {
    "href" : "some url of key 1",
    "name" : "key 1"
  },
  { 
    "href" : "some url of key 2",
    "name" : "key 2"
  },
  { 
    "href" : "some url of key 3",
    "name" : "key 3"
  },
  { 
    "href" : "some url of key 4",
    "name" : "key 4"
  }
    ...... and so on...
]
```

My main motive is to map or convert that result to my POJO class. How should I do or what would be the possible approach?

Comment: there are so many thing wrong that is difficult to start, first of all your pojo has nothing to do with the json you are parsing, there is no 'name' field in the json just objects with the href attribute, in order to parse anything crazy like this into a java pojo you will need an custom converter....

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
and it is really fast, strong and a good json parser

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference<HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>>() {};

Map<String, Map<String, String>> results = objectMapper.readValue(file, typeRef);
```

Comment: The question was not about JSON parsing, he already did that (using JsonPath.read(json, "$.links")).

Comment: @GeertPt I removed my answer - but I strongly doubt that you understood what Bacem and I tried to point at.

Comment: Your question :: 
"My main motivation is to map or convert that result to my POJO class."
I understood "deserialize json" and obtain the filled POJO  ? isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am expecting.

Comment: okay, so, with the converter you should be able to do it effeciently.